# Correct behaviour of Google ad in iOS

Tags: ios, google-ads-api

i am currently developing an app and i will need to implement google ad banner.

I am supposed to display the ad banner in the main view controller. But i have a side menu bar. Currently, when i open the side menu, the ad is blocked.

Is this a correct behaviour? Or is there any way that i can make the ad visible even when the side menu appears?

[image]

[image]

I know that for android, they would have a gap at the bottom to display the ad, so all the view controllers are shortened by the amount of the height the ad banner has?

Is that achievable in iOS as well?

Comment: Have you seen my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve the Android like behavior very easily in iOS too. 
Just create a Parent view controller and embed each controller in it.
Rest of the idea you can take from iADSuite below.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/iAdSuite_Storyboard/Listings/ContainerBanner_ContainerBanner_BannerViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013458-ContainerBanner_ContainerBanner_BannerViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_11

[image]